# Converting from Hash Set to Keyworded List

Tags: clojure, keyword, hashset, datomic

When querying the Datomic database, the result is something like

```
#{["Rainbows are many droplets acting as one" 17592186045438]
  ["Perception is malleable and changeable" 17592186045421]
  ["Dream preservation and posture" 17592186045440]}
```

What's a simple way to convert from #{} hash set to () list so I can use list operations like (nth-rand lst) on it?

And, how can I keywordize the different segments, so that they might look like :title, :content, :time, and so forth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an ordered collection, you can do something like sorting it, so you have control of the actual order the collection ends up as.

You would have to manually map over it and create hash maps with keywords as keys, the querying engine doesn't support returning hash maps.

Taking all of this into account, I would probably create the maps first, and then sort, for readability.

```
(->> (d/q '[:find ?name ?eid :where [...]] db)
  (map (fn [[name eid]] {:name name :eid eid}))
  (sort-by :eid))
```

You typically end up with your own little library of mapping functions like these, since you're basically working with what corresponds to the JDBC layer in traditional databases when calling the datomic peer lib.

Comment: very insightful, thank you for the clear exposition.  It makes sense what you say about working directly with the lower level of the jdbc, thanks for mentioning that! (=

Comment: May I ask why there are square brackets doubled around [[name eid]] in the map line?

Comment: This is "parameter de-structuring". When you `map` a function over a collection, your function will take an element of the collection as parameter. In your case, an element is a vector with 2 values `["blah blah" 123123]`. The de-structuring simplify the code and avoid you to access explicitly the first and second element of the vector.